# Not able to get excel file from web api dot net core 2.1 using epplus excel package

Tags: excel, asp.net-core-webapi, epplus

I'm trying to generate an excel file / stream in my web api and return it in a HttpResponseMessage to serve it to the client in Angular 5 as a download.

The generation succeeds and an xlsx file is generated and saved on the server, but when I return it in the Content of my httpResponseMessage, my browser shows just some json instead of the whole excel file.

```
{"version":{"major":1,"minor":1,"build":-1,"revision":-1,"majorRevision":-1,"minorRevision":-1},"content":{"headers":[{"key":"Content-Disposition","value":["attachment; filename=636742856488421817.xlsx"]},{"key":"Content-Type","value":["application/ms-excel"]},{"key":"Content-Length","value":["22780"]}]},"statusCode":200,"reasonPhrase":"OK","headers":[],"requestMessage":null,"isSuccessStatusCode":true}
```

This is how I create the excel file and returns it:

```
        var dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        var dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        httpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/ms-excel");
        httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
```

Comment: can you try with Chrome, and send us what chrome receive (from dev tools, F12)?

Comment: Since your excel is already on disk, you can only do this (this works on webapi 2.1, didn't tried on core) : 
`return File(fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, shortFileName);`

Comment: shortFileName is like "report.xlsx", and fileName is like "c:\report\report.xlsx".  You don't have to tell your client your local full path ;-)

Comment: Hi @DanielBlais, I already fixed it, and I used the same way you describing. 
I even removed the save and now im Returning the stream using File().

The problem I faced is that my logic was not in the Api Controller,m but in a helper class deeper. So File() didnt work.

Then I changed my method in the helper class to return a Stream instead of a Httpresponsemessage to the controller.

In my controller I return the file to thhe client using File().

Comment: And in Angular I use Blob().

See the answer below for the complete solution.

Thank you for your time DanielBlais

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:

Here is what I did

Helper class which creates the excel package and converts it to a Stream

```
var fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".xlsx";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileName);
FileInfo templateFile = new FileInfo(@"Templates/ReportTemplate.xlsx");
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file, templateFile);
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
... filling rows and cells goed here ...
var dataBytes = package.GetAsByteArray();
Stream dataStream = new MemoryStream(dataBytes);
dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return dataStream;
```

In the controller I return the file to the Angular client like this:

```
var stream = _helperClass.GenerateReport(exportDate, exportTitle);
return File(stream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", $"Report-{DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}.xlsx");
```

In the Angular component I do this after I receive the response:

```
var blob = new Blob([res], { type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" });
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var anchor = document.createElement("a");
anchor.download = `Report-${new Date().toISOString()}.xlsx`;
anchor.href = blobURL;
anchor.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this following code:

For conroller:
    [Route("DownLoadExcel")]
    public IActionResult DownLoadExcel()
    {
     var pack = new ExcelPackage();                    
     ExcelWorksheet worksheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sample");
     //First add the headers
     worksheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ID";
     worksheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Name";                   

     //Add values
     worksheet.Cells["A2"].Value = 1000;
     worksheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "Jon";
     return File(pack.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Sample.xlsx");
    }

For client side:

    window.open("../.../DownLoadExcel");
```